# My application don't work with GPS turned on

Tags: android, dictionary, gps

When I start the application(on Device) is displayed an extensible list, when I click on a child are displayed 2 points on a map and the road between them.
The application works fine when the WiFi is turned on, but if I turn on the GPS device, the map is displayed but the points are not displayed.

The code from AndroidManifest.xml is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="aexp.elistcbox"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    - <!--  Network related
  --> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
- <!--  Location related 
  --> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" /> 
- <!--  Wifi related  
  --> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_GPS" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CELL_ID" /> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" /> 

    <application android:label="@string/app_name">

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity android:name=".ElistCBox"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity android:name=".GPSLocatorActivity">
         </activity>
         <activity android:name="aexp.elistcbox.GlobalState"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking it on Emulator or on Device. If on Emulator then u need to turn on the GPS support through the go to your AVD select your AVD -> Edit -> Hardware -> New -> GPS support now check .... 
hope it helps !!!

Comment: And the location co-ordinates need to be sent to the emulator using "Emulator Control-> Location Controls" in DDMS

Comment: check with your Internet Connection, because if it were Emulator the above method works for all,since you are working it on device there is no Emulator Control. I Request You to test it on Emulator first...